# Where is the URL to download the package(tar) in archlinux packages page?

Tags: linux, archlinux, package-managers, pacman-package-manager

I get that `pacman` uses the mirrorlist and downloads the package tars from one of the mirrors.

But is there a place in https://archlinux.org/packages/ or https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ where I can get a URL to download a specific package?

Note: I'm not trying to troubleshoot anything.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For official packages, it's right there.

[image]

Everything in AUR is not compiled, you have to compile them yourself.

Comment: Except for packages with a -bin or -git suffix. More detailed [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543025/560504).